# Custom Color for Nav Bar Button and StatusBar for UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationbar, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a UIAlertController with a style of ActionSheet. There are 2 options. When a user selects anyone of them, it displays Apple's built in UIActivityViewController. The problem I'm having is that when a user then selects the Message or Mail and others, the **nav bar buttons are dark blue and the status bar is black.** I want the buttons to be white and the status bar to be white. The only thing that works correctly is that the Nav Bar color is blue which I set in the app delegate.

The code I have in App Delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Nav Bar
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().opaque = true
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = primaryBlueColor
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // Status Bar
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```

When I present the UIActivityViewController, I'm able to customize the color of the "Cancel" button to a custom blue. But again, when the user presses the Message or any other options, it goes to a new screen and the colors are not correct. This is what I have:

```
 let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [textFile], applicationActivities: nil)

 self.presentViewController(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)

 activityController.view.tintColor = primaryBlueColor
```

**EDIT TO QUESTION 1:**

I just found the answer for the buttons to change to the color white. Now all that is missing is the Status Bar to turn white. This is what I added to the App Delegate method above.

```
 UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UINavigationBar.classForCoder()]).tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Any suggestions for the status bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AppDelegate, you can delete:

```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent`
```

Next, add the following code to your ViewController:

```
extension UINavigationController {

   public override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
       return .LightContent
   }

   public override func childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle() -> UIViewController? {
       return nil
   } 
}
```

Finally, go into your Info.plist and set:

`View controller-based status bar appearance = YES`

Comment: It works! Thanks so much. There seems to be one issue with the button colors. If I click Message, the buttons are white. But if I click Mail, the buttons are blue on the new screen that comes up. Any idea why?

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding. Also, for me, the "Send" button in Mail was off-color until I entered a recipient address. Or is the issue you're experiencing completely different?

Comment: I tried cleaning and rebuilding and still nothing. Both the Cancel and Send button is blue. Even when I start typing, the Send button is blue. As for Message, it is perfect. Not sure if this is a separate issue. Any idea why? Did you have this issue at all?

Comment: I haven't had this issue. It may be something else in the code you're running though. Are you accessing MFMailComposeViewController() anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Yes I am, I have a Settings screen so users can send an email for support. Everything is working perfect for that screen. Is there anything I need to change here?

Comment: Do you think the MFMailComposeViewController() on the other screen is the problem?

Comment: I deleted the app for the fifth time and cleaned the project and it works now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To change the status bar to white, in swift, go to `info.plist`, and press the `+`and edit it like so:

[image]

Then, add this line to the `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
 // Changing the status bar's colour to white
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that code in my question. I already had this. I edited my question above. So this code works for every screen except when I press UIActivityViewController and then select an option like Message and Mail. The status bar shows up as white and 1 second later turns to black. Any suggestions?